# Bumpversion: reset any part of the version

Tags: python, version

I am using the bumpversion utility (https://github.com/peritus/bumpversion) to version my python package but have run into an issue. I have it in the format of [major].[minor]-[release] eg: "10.1-qa". My config file looks like the following:

```
[bumpversion]
current_version = 10.1-qa
parse = (?P<major>\d+)\.(?P<minor>\d+)(\-(?P<release>[a-z]+))?
serialize = 
    {major}.{minor}-{release}
    {major}.{minor}

[bumpversion:part:release]
optional_value = rel
first_value = qa
values = 
    qa
    rc
    rel
```

What i want is to reset the release part to qa anytime I bump the major or minor part. Currently it only does so when bumping the major part. I'll appreciate any help in this regard as I havent been able to find an example online